# Rspec test failing when output indicates it should pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
**Edit/Update**
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Ok, I fixed the tests that were failing to pass by appending a ".to_s" to each user.password_digest in the change blocks.  I assume this is working because before user.password_digest was sort of like a pointer, and calling "to_s" forces the test to compare the string values.  If anyone can explain why the test compares the pointer and not the value, please enlighten me.

After adding the .to_s calls (added everywhere I was expecting a user attribute to change), Failure #3 is still occurring (and a new failure, actually, but I'm sure it's caused by the same issue causing Failure #3).  Any ideas why the test "correct user with correct password should change email" isn't catching the change action that happens correctly in the browser?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I'm trying to validate behavior of a form to update a user's profile (change email and/or password).  3 of my tests are failing, and I can't figure out why.  Take a look at the console output when I run the tests...

```
Failures:
  1) User Pages Edit page correct user updates password with incorrect password should not change password
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button "Save" }.not_to change{ user.password_digest }
       result should not have changed, but did change from "$2a$10$Xrg1SHSyDmK5Of9HrjgYAuzkJzKk7HeaVjj4ZT9Ldz2R9BNji3D2S" to "$2a$10$Xrg1SHSyDmK5Of9HrjgYAuzkJzKk7HeaVjj4ZT9Ldz2R9BNji3D2S"
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:135:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User Pages Edit page correct user updates password with confirmation mismatch should not change password
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button "Save" }.not_to change{ user.password_digest }
       result should not have changed, but did change from "$2a$10$bm2viuIuNCRIEEWe/qYVAOVl0r0EW7Y/1CqalKUwgR.ht/wVtQ8Zi" to "$2a$10$bm2viuIuNCRIEEWe/qYVAOVl0r0EW7Y/1CqalKUwgR.ht/wVtQ8Zi"
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:147:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User Pages Edit page correct user updates email with correct password should change email
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button "Save" }.to change{ user.email }.to(new_email)
       result should have been changed to "new_email@example.com", but is now "person_7@example.com"
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:121:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.99 seconds
8 examples, 3 failures
```

Failures #1 & 2 should be passing, right?  The before and after strings match, and they're expected not to change!  What could be going on here?

Furthermore, I can't figure out why failure #3 is happening.

The code works as expected in the browser.  Could it have something to do with AJAX?  The update action the form is hitting doesn't redirect_to anything -- it just renders the page again with flash notices.  I'm a Rails newbie so I'm probably missing something obvious.

The form:

```
<%= form_tag user_path(params[:id]), method: :put do %>

    <%= label_tag :email %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] || @user.email %>

    <%= label_tag :new_password %>
    <%= password_field_tag :new_password %>

    <%= label_tag :new_password_confirmation, "Confirm new password" %>
    <%= password_field_tag :new_password_confirmation %>

    <%= label_tag :password %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>

    <%= submit_tag "Save", class: "btn btn-primary pull-down" %>
<% end %>
```

The tests spec (unrelated tests removed for clarity):

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "User Pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "Edit page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    describe "correct user" do
      before do
        log_in user # helper method that logs the user in, a la Michael Hartl tutorial
        visit edit_user_path(user)
      end

      it { current_path.should == edit_user_path(user) }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Edit') }
      it { should_not have_content('not authorized') }

      describe "updates email" do
        let(:new_email) { "new_email@example.com" }
        before { fill_in 'Email', with: new_email }

        describe "with incorrect password" do
          it "should not change email" do
            expect { click_button "Save" }.not_to change{ user.email }
          end
        end

        describe "with correct password" do
          before { fill_in 'Password', with: user.password }
          it "should change email" do
            expect { click_button "Save" }.to change{ user.email }.to(new_email)
          end
        end
      end

      describe "updates password" do

        describe "with incorrect password" do
          before do
            fill_in 'New password', with: 'newpassword'
            fill_in 'Confirm new password', with: 'newpassword'
          end

          it "should not change password" do
            expect { click_button "Save" }.not_to change{ user.password_digest }
          end
        end

        describe "with confirmation mismatch" do
          before do
            fill_in 'New password', with: 'newpassword'
            fill_in 'Confirm new password', with: 'password'
            fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
          end

          it "should not change password" do
            expect { click_button "Save" }.not_to change{ user.password_digest }
          end
        end

        describe "with correct password" do
          before do
            fill_in 'New password', with: 'newpassword'
            fill_in 'Confirm new password', with: 'newpassword'
            fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
          end

          it "should change password" do
            expect { click_button "Save" }.to change{ user.password_digest }
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Relevant gem versions: Rails 3.2.9, Capybara 1.1.2, FactoryGirl 4.1.0